# How does this regular expression with capturing group and backreference match in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I'm having hard time understanding what a certain Java regex would match:

```
"<(\\w+)></\\1>"
```

I've read through this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

But I still can't figure out what that expression would match to, especially the `\1` part.  I can see that `<(\w+)>` is a possessive quantifier matching any word but I don't understand why use the `()` which according to the tutorial are for matching a group.

As for the second part, I just don't know what `\1` would match.  I tried it with

```
"001123344556678899".replaceAll("\\1", "");
```

since I thought just maybe it matches a number, but it gave me back my string as is nothing replaced.

Comment: See the ["Backreference" subsection of the "Capturing Groups" section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) in that tutorial.

Comment: i can't believe i missed that, it actually has the \1 explained, thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's intended to match pairs of XML/HTML tags, such as

```
<tag></tag>
```

The `\\1` means match to the first matched group, i.e. the thing in the parentheses. (The double backslash is because backslashes need to be escaped in Java string literals.)

Comment: Thanks Simon, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood the tutorial.  Anything inside `()` are a set, so `(\w{1})(\w{1})` would mean you have 2 sets having 1 character in each. the `\1`, reference the first set. So it is more like this in you search and replace:

```
"1234234234234".replaceAll("(23)", "\\1ab")
```

and the result would be `"123ab423ab423ab..."`, `\1` returns you what you match in your first set.

Comment: thanks you for the help, althought "1234234234234".replaceAll("(23)", "\1ab") wouldn't work since the second param of replaceAll isn't evaluated as a Regex

Comment: @K-SaMa did not think about that. But you are right, the replacement string is not treated as regex.

Comment: In the replacement string you use `$1` to refer to the first group, not `\1`.  And they are called *groups*, not *sets*.  Also, `{1}` doesn't do anything but add clutter to the regex and confuse n00b's; please don't use it.

Comment: @alan-moore good one Alan, that `$1` is quite helpful, thanks!

Comment: Be aware that some languages/tools *do* use `\1`, `\2`, etc., and some will take either form.  Here's a quick [overview](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just refresh your understanding of regex backreferences (and capturing groups), e.g. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html). Capturing group uses `()` and backreference would be replaced by data captured by referenced group.

Then use [this site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to test your expression and your data like this:

Regular Expression: `<(\w+)></\1>` would become a Java string `"<(\\w+)></\\1>"` with input like this `<body></body>`:

```
Test    Target String   matches()   replaceFirst()  replaceAll()    group(0)    group(1)

1       <body></body>   Yes         Yes             Yes             <body></body> body
```